# jquery animate does not work on mouseover

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate

I just wrote a jquery, and I have no idea why is isn't working. Any help is appreciated!

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("navbar").mouseover(function(){
        $("navbar").animate({height:'60px'});
}
$("navbar").mouseout(function(){
    $("navbar").animate({height:'40px'});
    }
});
```

I want it to be that when you mouse over it, it grows taller, and when your mouse leaves, it goes back to normal (40px)
Navbar is a div later on btw.

Comment: `$("navbar")` selects an element with **tag name** "navbar". Is that really what you want? You probably have an element with **ID** "navbar".

Comment: Show your HTML. I think you want $("#navbar")

Comment: $("navbar") = is this class or id? Please define it in jQuery

Comment: We need your HTML; what is is doing ("not working" doesn't help us) and what it should be doing.

Comment: It appears that you are not closing your `mouseover` and `mouseout` handlers correctly. You have "}" but it needs to be "});" Check your browser console for javascript errors.

Comment: Oh sorry forgot to mention that the # didn't help. Thanks Felix Kling though, that seemed to be the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define `navbar` as either an ID or a class by using `.navbar` or `#navbar` right now it's trying to select an HTML element called `<navbar></navbar>`